# How to parse the Json data in WP8?

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I'm newbie to windows phone 8 development. I am working on application in which I need parse the Json. please help me with this json data

```
{
    "School": [
        {
            "info": {
                "name": "Dary",
                "description": "Student",
                "startAt": "",
                "endAt": "",
                "status": "approved",
                "type": 7
            },
            "gui": {
                "size": 60,
                "sizeMB": "1.7 M"
            }
        },
        {
            "info": {
                "name": "Henry",
                "description": "Student",
                "startAt": "",
                "endAt": "",
                "status": "approved",
                "type": 7
            },
            "gui": {
                "size": 60,
                "sizeMB": "1.7 M"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

this is class

```
    public class Info
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string startAt { get; set; }
        public string endAt { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Gui
    {
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string sizeMB { get; set; }
    }

    public class School
    {
        public Info info { get; set; }
        public Gui gui { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<School> School { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? JSON.NET is a popular library that you can get as an Extension from within Visual Studio.

Comment: You can also use the Newtonsoft.Json library for performing same operation.

Comment: I have added but didn't know the parse :(

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia, they are one and the same

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Torr suggests, [JSON.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/) is a great option. There is a [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for serialization in the .net framework, but its not very robust. You can easily add JSON.NET to your project with Nuget. Place your json in a string variable

```
 string json = "<<your json string>>"
```

or read from a file

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("<<path to file>>");
```

Then, the following code will deserialize your text.

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

You can lose the root object (it looks like it came from a javascript to C# converter) if you keep only the json array (the text between the brackets [] ), and then you can deserialize just the array.

```
  List<School> school = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<School>>(json);
```

Comment: "thank" I could not complete the code, can you help me complete the foreach loop

Comment: foreach (var i in root.campaign)
                    {
                       ????
                    }

Comment: foreach (var school in root.schools){ console.WriteLine(school.info.name); }

Comment: root.schools is Null :(

Comment: It should be root.School as per your datamodel. If it still returns null, paste your full json.

Comment: Yes. root.School. Sorry for the typo. The compiler is your friend, and should catch simple errors like that for you.